# Custom Toast Positioning

Tags: android, android-layout, toast

I have created a custom view for my Toast Messages.

I want my toast messages to take up the width of the screen with say 30dp margin in left and right.

But it ends up, filling up the entire screen, if the text/content of the Toast message is long.(and wraps up a lot , if the content is less). I want it to remain the same size in Width ( i.e. entire screen width minus margin at left and right) , and height to wrap(increase/decrease) as per the content in it.

This is my current Toast Xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toast_root"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/jtoast_bg"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp">
<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/toast_image"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
     android:scaleType="fitStart"
     android:src="@drawable/menu_info">
</ImageView>
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/toast_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="toast text"
    android:textColor="#FFF">
 </TextView>
```

and it is being populated as :

```
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.jtoast,(ViewGroup)activity.findViewById(R.id.toast_root));
..
toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 40, 40);
..
```

Comment: Im having the same issue with my toast not respecting the bottom padding if the message is too long. Ever find a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/toast_root"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="#990099"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
    >
<View
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/toast_root"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#999900"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        >
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toast_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_btn_search"
            >
    </ImageView>
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toast_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:text="toast text"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#ff00"
            />
</LinearLayout>
<View
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: nope, done `layout_width` to `fill_parent` for Layout,textview; margins on left,right are still not working, occupying the full width again. Moreover, if the text in the textview is long..some of the text is lost in the view...

Answer (score 0):

You can also modify your default toast by setting gravity params

This is kotlin example:

```
fun showToast(context: Context, message: String, long: Boolean = false) {
    val duration: Int

    if (long) duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG
    else duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT

    Toast.makeText(context, message, duration).apply {
        setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, dp2px(76))
        show()
    }
}
```